# Div headers do not align on a web page

Tags: html, css

I have a homepage on the website I am building where there are two rows of content. Each row contains 2 paragraphs; each have a heading and associated buttons. For example:

```
                                    This is the second paragraph
This is the first paragraph         and it does not line up
"content...................         "content....................
..........................          .............................
.........................."         ............................."
                                    |BUTTON|
```

The problem is that I want the headers in each div to line up with each other; the first line of each header should line up. Here is my code for the div:

```
/* Home page introductory paragraphs layout */
div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    padding-left: 75px;
    padding-right: 75px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

Is there a way to specify that the header is to always be at the top of the block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) value is `baseline`. You can set it to `top` if you need the elements to be top aligned.

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top; /*NEW*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make two divs are aligned same on top. How about using fixed position tag

```
position:fixed:
top:40px;
```

Please try it and let me know further requirements.

```
.a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    padding-left: 75px;
    padding-right: 75px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    position:fixed:
    top:40px;
}
```

Comment: When tried that it placed all the divs on top of each other